# What will happen if I try to print an impossible solid into a 3D printer?

Tags: 3d

What would be the result of a 3D modeled impossible solid, like the Penrose Triangle, printed out of a 3D printer?

Comment: Something like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Penrosetrianglemodel.jpg

Comment: How would you describe an impossible solid to a 3d printer?

Comment: An "impossible" solid is just a solid that, in some 2d projection or viewed from some angle, appears as another solid. That's all.

Comment: None of the modeling software I've used allows you to build impossible shapes. The rules of euclidean geometry are implicitly included in the software.

Comment: "closed as not constructive" How appropriate :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gershon Elber of the Computer Science Department at Technion in Isreal works on creating similar objects by way of introducing contortions of 3D printed media, that when viewed from the right angle, produce the appropriate visual illusion of an impossible objects.

Here is his work on [Escher For Real](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gershon/EscherForReal/) and a Youtube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmr4HqjSSw4) demonstrating the technique and 3D printed fabrication.